# Continents at Where I want to work?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Continents is important at "Where do you want to work?", because lot of developers from Europe's countries haven't problem working at other European Union countries.

My proposal

- Europe (European Union)
- Middle East (UEA, Saudi Arabia or Qatar)
- Caribbean

Comment: Similarly, Australian and New Zealand citizens can freely live/work in both countries.

Comment: +1 Currently Europe or EU is not recognized.

Answer (score 4):

There was an exception in saving continents, but this has been fixed.

We're using the awesome [Yahoo!](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/) location service right now - here's an example Europe query:

> http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22Europe%22&format=xml

This will give us a nice bounding box to help determine searches on your specified continents, regions, etc - whatever Yahoo! supports.

We'll be adding more features around locations ASAP - we just needed lots of live data to help us out :)

Answer (score 2):

Also: regions.  Like Mid West, North East, West Coast, etc.